Difficulty understanding the meaning of "volume" with the scalar triple product
I am computing the scalar triple product of two vectors a, b, and their orthogonal cross product c. A special case of this is where a x b = c, which leads to the scalar triple product equalling 0.
My textbook states:


The volume of the parallelepiped determined by the vectors a, b,
and c is the magnitude of their scalar triple product:

V = |a ⋅ (b x c)|
If we use the formula in (14) and discover that the volume of the parallelepiped determined by a, b, and c is 0, then the vectors must lie in the same plane; that is, they are coplanar.
EXAMPLE 5 Use the scalar triple product to show that the vectors a = <1, 4, -7>, b = <2, -1, 4>, and c = <0, -9, 18> are coplanar.
SOLUTION  We use Equation 13 to compute their scalar triple product:
a ⋅ (b x c) = ... = 0
Therefore, by (14), the volume of the parallelepiped determined by a,
b, and c is 0. This means that a, b, and c are coplanar.

EDIT: In the textbook example, a is orthogonal to (b x c), which was not obvious to me. Which explains why a, b, and c are coplanar. I had to graph these using GeoGebra to see that.
Also, a ⋅ (a x b) = (a x b) ⋅ a = b ⋅ (a x b) = (a x b) ⋅ b = 0.
However, I am perplexed by the use of the word "volume" to explain this scalar triple product. This 3D parallelepiped would definitely have positive volume [EDIT: if they were not coplanar, which they actually are in the example above], so why is the dot product of the cross product described as being the volume?
Consider the special case of vector a, which is orthogonal to b, and their cross product c which is orthogonal to both. This forms a special parallelepiped which is a rectangular prism, whose volume can be computed by V=|a||b||c|. This will definitely be a positive volume for non-zero vectors, and yet this scalar triple product is also described as "volume" and its value will be 0.
Please help me understand. What am I missing?
EDIT: I was missing that there was quite literally 0 volume because the example of the scalar triple product in Stewart Calculus 8th edition used coplanar vectors. Also, the definition of being coplanar makes far more sense now.

Are you asking: 1. Why people would say that a flat box of height 0 has volume 0? 2. Why a particular scalar triple product in a part of your textbook is 0? or 3. Why, when you calculate the scalar triple product of a setup in your last paragraph gives 0 when the volume of a rectangular box with nonzero lengths is clearly not 0?

Nowhere in your quote does it say that $a\times b = c$ implies the triple product is zero. I can't imagine the book says that anywhere, and you haven't made it clear why you think it says that.

@NicholasTodoroff It does say that. Stewart Calculus 8th edition. However, what I did not realize was that in that example a is orthogonal to (b x c). I had to graph them using GeoGebra to see that. It now makes sense why they're coplanar. If instead of being coplanar a, b, and c belonged to the edges of a 3D box/rectangular prism, they would give the same result as V=|a||b||c| for the volume of that box.

"It does say that." Show us, or at least give a page number. What you have written is incorrect, and I find it highly implausible that you would find such incorrect statements in a widely-used calculus textbook.

@DavidK It's from page 860 of Stewart Calculus 8th edition, Example 5. I have also edited the question to add more detail from the example.


I am computing the scalar triple product of two vectors $a$, $b$, and their orthogonal cross product $c$. A special case of this is where $a \times b = c$, which leads to the scalar triple product equalling $0$.

This could be the source of your difficulty. The scalar triple product is plain and simply a function  of three vectors. There is no requirement that one of the vectors be the "orthogonal cross product" (is there any other kind of cross product?) of the third vector.
One notation
for the scalar triple product of $a$, $b$, and $c$ (which can be any three vectors) is $[a,b,c]$. The scalar triple product can be computed using any of these formulas:
\begin{align}
[a,b,c] &= a \cdot (b \times c) \\
&= b \cdot (c \times a) \\
&= c \cdot (a \times b). \\
\end{align}
In the textbook example, $b - 2a = c$. That's an easy way to show that the vectors are coplanar without computing any cross products.

Consider the special case of vector $a$, which is orthogonal to $b$, and their cross product $c$ which is orthogonal to both. This forms a special parallelepiped which is a rectangular prism, whose volume can be computed by $V=|a|*|b|*|c|$. This will definitely be a positive volume for non-zero vectors, and yet this scalar triple product is also described as "volume" and its value will be $0$.

Shall we try a numerical example?
Let $a = \langle 2, 0, 0\rangle$ and $b = \langle 0, 3, 0\rangle$.
Let $c = a \times b = \langle 0, 0, 6\rangle$.
Then the scalar triple product of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is
\begin{align}
[a,b,c] &= a \cdot (b \times c) \\
&= \langle 2, 0, 0\rangle \cdot (\langle 0,3,0\rangle \times \langle 0,0,6\rangle) \\
&= \langle 2, 0, 0\rangle \cdot \langle 18,0,0\rangle \\
&= 36 \\
&= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 6 \\
&= \lVert a\rVert \lVert b\rVert \lVert c\rVert .
\end{align}
So the scalar triple product works perfectly to produce the expected volume in this case. Why did you think the scalar triple product would be zero?
It is true that sometimes the scalar triple product of non-coplanar vectors is negative, whereas volume is positive. That's why we take the absolute value of the scalar triple product when we want volume.

I think I was just primarily confused by the initial presentation of the concept in the Stewart 8th edition textbook. After graphing it in 3D, it became far more obvious why a, b, and c were considered coplanar vectors. By extension, it became clear why the volume of coplanar vectors under the scalar triple product equaled 0. The textbook also happens introduce the concept of coplanar vectors in that same example for the first time, which did not help! Frankly, it should have started with a simple example first, like the example you demonstrated here :)

We have that the dot product of two vectors is the area of the paralellogram determined by the vectors $a$ and $b$. The volume of a parallelepiped is the area of the base time height. The area of the base is the area of the paralellogram determined by $a$ and $b$, so we have the dot product. Since the cross product $c$ is orthogonal to both $a$ and $b$, it is the height of the parallelepiped. Thus, the volume of the parallelepiped is $(a \cdot b) \times c$, which is equivalent to $a \cdot (b \times c)$.

Your first sentence is quite incorrect. The rest is also incorrect.
